# How can I change the order in which update-desktop-database puts the applications supporting a mimetype?

Tags: xdg, xdg-open

I am running manjaro linux which is built on top of Arch Linux. I use cinnamon desktop environment occasionally and Awesome for the rest.

I am trying to figure out how I can get the system to choose the defaults differently when I install several packages that support a certain mime-type. For example, on my system I have pcmanfm, nemo and sunflower all of which handle inode/directory. By default, the `update-desktop-database` generates a line like below in `/usr/share/applications/mimieinfo.cache` which makes sunflower the default.

`inode/directory=sunflower.desktop;pcmanfm.desktop;nemo.desktop;`

I can override this by adding entries in `.config/mimeapps.list` but my question is about if I can influence the order of the entries in the system-wide defaults.

In this case, e.g, I like sunflower a lot but when I am opening folders from other applications (e.g., deluge) I want them to be opened in PCMan File manager. Ultimately these apps use xdg-open which [uses](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open) the `mimeinfo.cache` or one of the overrides to launch the right handler.

How can I change the order in which these applications are listed in the mimeinfo.cache ?

Answer (score 5):

You can not change the order (see also https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71932).

To change the default application system-wide you have to create a file `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. For example if you want that all PDF files will be opened with MuPDF add:

```
[Default Applications]
application/pdf=mupdf.desktop
```

I am not sure if you are still looking for an answer but I asked myself the same question and thought that my findings might also help others.

Comment: If you have an ancient Linux installation, try `defaults.list` instead of `mimeapps.list`.